# setVisibility в фрагменте, recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть фрагмент, в нём `recyclerView`, состоящий из следующей разметки:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/recyclefragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"
    android:id="@+id/subheader"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Очевидно длинный текст"
        android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rvWords"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/subheader"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar"
/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#757575"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:paddingLeft="64dp"
        android:paddingRight="64dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/filter"
            android:text="button 1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/sort"
            android:text="button 2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/suggest_term"
            android:text="button 3" />


    </FrameLayout>
```

Проблема в том, что необходимо скрывать и показывать `subHeader` при скролле. Написал простенькую анимацию, все работает.

Лишь с одной неприятной особенностью,а именно - при исчезновении уходит `ViewGroup` вместе с  `TextView`, и остается пустое пространство.

Ладно - подумал я, и дополнил свои методы появлением и исчезновением `view`.
Выглядеть стало примерно так:

```
      private void hideView() {
        subheader.animate().translationY(-subheader.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));
        subheader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

     private void showView() {
        subheader.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
        subheader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
 rvContacts.setOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollSubheader() {
            @Override
            public void onHide() {
                hideView();

            }

            @Override
            public void onShow() {
                showView();

            }
        });


    }
```

Однако, по мере скролла его начинает конкретно дергать в самые разные стороны, то показывая, то пряча.

Реализация скролла:

```
    public abstract class HidingScrollSubheader extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private static final int HIDE_THRESHOLD = 15;
    private int scrolledDistance = 0;
    private boolean controlsVisible = true;


    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if (scrolledDistance > HIDE_THRESHOLD && controlsVisible) {
            onHide();
            controlsVisible = false;
            scrolledDistance = 0;
        } else if (scrolledDistance < -HIDE_THRESHOLD && !controlsVisible) {
            onShow();
            controlsVisible = true;
            scrolledDistance = 0;
        }

        if ((controlsVisible && dy > 0) || (!controlsVisible && dy < 0)) {
            scrolledDistance += dy;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onHide();

    public abstract void onShow();
}
```

Я понимаю, что в каком-то месте ошибся, и не там прячу\показываю вью, однако в упор не могу найти ошибку.

Comment: Сдаётся мне вы тут CoordinatorLayout пытаетесь переизобрести. Вот неплохая [статья о нем](https://habrahabr.ru/post/270121/)

Comment: @xkor фрагмент не находится в `Coordinator Layout`, соответственно и флаги не работают.
Пробовал - предлагаете обернуть в него?

Comment: ну если вам нужен функционал который есть в `CoordinatorLayout` то почему бы им не воспользоваться? По поводу флагов не понял, что ещё за флаги?

Comment: @xkor например этот:
`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"`