# Анимация viewgroup

Tags: android, android-animation

Необходимо написать простенькую анимацию исчезновения и появления `header` над списком. При скролле вниз, он должен исчезать, при скролле вверх возвращаться обратно.

На данный момент меня застали 2 препятствия:

1)Исчезает только содержимое `linear layout` в котором находится `textview`, то есть само "поле" остается, и пропадает только текст.

2)После окончания анимации текст возвращается на место(переопределял `AnimatorListener` - об этом ниже).

Сразу скажу, что вещи вроде :

```
 public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                View text = subheader.findViewById(R.id.header_text);
                text.setAlpha(0);
            }
```

являются простыми заглушками\попытками разобраться, конкретно здесь я `header` задавал альфу. Для упрощения она сразу включается при создании фрагмента.

Вот код:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        subheader = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.subheader);
        animationSubheaderShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.header_show);

        subheader.animate().setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                View text = subheader.findViewById(R.id.header_text);
                text.setAlpha(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });

        subheader.startAnimation(animationSubheaderShow);


        return view;
    }
```

Разметка:

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/subheader"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="#F0F0F0"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/header_text"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="42 nouns in ability topic(sort by rating)"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Анимация:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: Может вам не анимация нужна, но CoordinatorLayout, коий будет при скроле чего-нибудь скролить что-то ещё другое?

Comment: соглашусь с ЮрийСПб в данном случае лучше использовать CoordinatorLayout. обеспечение поведения различных вьюх в зависимости друг от друга это его прямая обязанность))

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ Если допустим, буду использовать CoordinatorLayout, то через него скроллить "что то еще другое" с помощью чего?app:layout_behavior = ?

Comment: @Asgard, ну, да... Просто посмотрите любой пример реализации. Вот один: https://github.com/mohaxspb/RxRetrofitAndScreenOrientation/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml - там просто Toolbar еузжает/появляется при скроле.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это не подходит, нужно 5 секунд для скрытия, поэтому и начал использовать анимации. Ответьте хотя-бы на один вопрос, будьте добры.

Comment: @Asgard а зачем вам 5 секунд для скрытия?.. за такое время пользователь может просто перестать скролить и вообще перейти к другим действиям.

Comment: Может вам просто надо скрыть вьюху? Т.е. View.setVisibility(View.GONE)?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пробовал - поведение то же самое.

Comment: @Asgard, ну... А на чём пробовали? Надо на subheader

Comment: @ЮрийСПб именно на нем и пробовал, со всеми элементами. Это поле остается (которое `viewgroup`)

Comment: @Asgard, мне кажется что вы какие-то важные детали не упомянули...  Вообще у вас сейчас собственно исчезновения нет. Только установка прозрачности. Убрать можно назначением видимости, как я выше указал, назначением 0-ой высоты вьюхе или изменением её координат так, чтобы она за экраном скрылась.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я пытался так делать еще с момента, когда писал [вот это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524309/setvisibility-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-recyclerview).
Важных деталей - например каких?Есть `textView` - сделал `setVisibility(View.GONE)` все работает и это вполне понятно. Но если я пытаюсь сделать подобное с `viewGroup` (LinearLayout, FrameLayout, RelativeLayout) - то исчезает само содержимое, но не всё поле.

Comment: @Asgard, странно, должно работать... Попробуйте высоту в wrap_content поставить. Ну и посмотрите что происходит при включённом "показать границы макета" в настройках разработчика.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб она остается, попробовал и так и эдак.

Comment: @Asgard, и высоту в 0 ставили и она всё равно не пропадала?.. 0_о